# SignalR Secure Connection Between .NET Client and The Server

Tags: asp.net, signalr

On SignalR .NET, we establish a connection as below between the client and server:

```
var connection = new HubConnection("http://mysite/");
```

Next, we subscribe the events and start the connection as below:

```
connection.Start().Wait();
```

What if I would like to establish a secure connection between the client and server. How can we achieve that with current features?

I noticed that there is a property type of `System.Net.ICredentials` on `HubConnection` class. Is this the way for this? If so, how should we handle the Auth at the server side for our Hubs?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is how I have mine set up:

```
  var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://siteurl");
  hubConnection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
  hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateProxy("My.Hub.Namespace");

  hubConnection.Start().Wait();
```

You could of course pass in different credentials, I use [DefaultNetworkCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultnetworkcredentials.aspx)

> The credentials returned by DefaultNetworkCredentials represents the authentication credentials for the current security context in which the application is running. For a client-side application, these are usually the Windows credentials (user name, password, and domain) of the user running the application. For ASP.NET applications, the default network credentials are the user credentials of the logged-in user, or the user being impersonated.

Comment: Ok, this is nice. How do you auth the user on the server with those credentials? How does SignalR manage this?

Comment: SignalR isn't involved in authentication at all. It simply passes through the credentials from the underlying host. In the case of the sample above, you'd need to have your SignalR be protected using Windows Authentication for the default network credentials to do anything. Then you can authorize the user based on your own logic (is user "Bob" allowed to call hub method "Foo"?)

Comment: @DamianEdwards so, can we say that creating a desktop chat application which has user based auth (just like Windows Live Messagner) with SignalR is not a good idea (at least for now)? You guys have JabbR as IRC which has forms-auth. Do you have any desktop auth sample which I can have a look and grasp the idea?

Comment: @tugberk I don't think that is what Damian meant. What he means is that authentication happens outside of signalr. I use windows auth in my silverlight app and it works great. You just need to turn on Windows Authentication on your IIS server (and turn off Anonymous) and the code above should work with a 401 auth challenge.

Comment: @AndyMay thanks Andy! I still cannot imagine how to pass the credentials from my desktop app to IIS. Do you suggest that I should check the permissions on my desktop app and if they are valid then I should allow SignalR to run?

Comment: @AndyMay: I'm trying to use windows auth in a silverlight app with signalR but getting the same issue as the OP. I've ensure windows auth is the only one setup in IIS and made a webapi call before setting up signalR client side so I know client is authenticated.  Any other gotchas you can suggest might be tripping me up?

Comment: I had same situation and even I used `DefaultNetworkCredentials` it doesn't worked for me. i still get `unauthorized` exception