# SignalR not calling client-side function when handling an event in NServiceBus

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nservicebus, signalr

I have an MVC app that I am displaying records from the DB and I give the ability to create a new record.  I am using SignalR to notify the clients when the IEvent handler from Nservicebus   has completed.

**Index.cshtml**

```
<script src="signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    var myHub;

    $(function () {
        myHub = $.connection.userAccountHub;

        //add handler to handle the nofication
        myHub.testMsg = function () {
            alert("I would really like for this to work");
        };

        $.connection.hub.start();
    }); 
</script>
```

**UserController.cs**

```
public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IBus _bus;    


public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(getalldata());
        }


[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(CreateUserAccountModel user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _bus.Send(new CreateUserAccountCommand
                {
                    FirstName = user.FirstName,
                    LastName = user.LastName,
                    NetworkLogin = user.NetworkLogin
                });

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(user);
        }
```

**UserAccountHub**

```
public class UserAccountHub : Hub
    {

    }
```

**UserAccountCreatedNotifyEventHandler.cs**

```
public class UserAccountCreatedNotifyEventHandler : IHandleMessages<UserAccountCreatedNotifyEvent>
    {
        public void Handle(UserAccountCreatedNotifyEvent message)
        {
            IConnectionManager connectionManager = AspNetHost.DependencyResolver.Resolve<IConnectionManager>();
            dynamic clients = connectionManager.GetClients<UserAccountHub>();

            clients.testMsg();
        }
    }
```

Basically I go to the Index action which just displays all my records and has a create button.  I click on the create button `@Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create", null, null)` and it called the `public ActionResult Create(CreateUserAccountModel user)` method. To start the bus and then redirects to the index action.  The service bus does its thing and `UserAccountCreatedNotifyEventHandler Handle` method is triggered appropriately.

This is where I start to see some problems. I call the appropriate signalr methods to get the clients so I can broadcast a message `.testMsg()` however the clients aren't receiving the message.

So in short my signalr `clients.testMsg` call isnt acting as expected.  To my knowledge I am following the code examples I have found on the web, and even other test projects I have.  I am assuming I am doing something silly, but just cant target it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your handler you need to create a proxy to the hub and call the method on the proxy. Well, inject the proxy since creating it every time would be expensive!

See http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client

Comment: I use a similar pattern but from rabbitmq handlers

Comment: I actually found a problem with my NServicebus config that fixed a little of the problem.  What is odd now, is that my above code works the first time, but doesnt work after.  I am about ready to dig in and try the .CreateProxy method.

Comment: OK, I have more information.  I was unable to get the CreateProxy methodology working due to 401 unauthorized errors (seen via fiddler) when trying to start the connection.  I also further tested my code from above and more mystery is being added for me.  If I open up 2 browsers and just leave the 2nd browser open, it works as expected all the time.  Fiddler does show an authorized error for  http://localhost/DiscoverWeb/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionId.......    Any insight?

Comment: I am thinking it has to do with the fact that the NServicebus is a separate service.

Comment: Windows authentication.  I tried adding my windows credentials to the connection.credentials to no avail.  Been looking down this route:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503963/signalr-client-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-401-unauthorized

Comment: the auth story in signalr is pretty week. adding the network credential when you create the proxy should work. Help available on http://jabbr.net/#/rooms/signalr

Comment: Thanks for helping me via jabbr.net, helped me get past my handful of bonehead mistakes.

Comment: @redsquare I'm having an issue with connecting to a hub using a HubConnection in a NSB handler with the RabbitMQ transport. It hits the await hubConnection.Start() line and never returns. If I switch to the MSMQ transport, it connects just fine. Any ideas? Here's my GitHub repo: https://github.com/gabrieljoelc/SignalRDemos/blob/appharbor/SignalRDemos.Messages.Server/SignalRProxyConnection.cs.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
myHub.client.testMsg = function(){....}
```

not

```
myHub.testMsg = function(){....}
```